# Alignment error setting limits on x-axis

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I'm working with a data set that uses months as a discrete x-axis variable. I have data that spans 3 years and all 12 months. I want to generate a box plot that only shows the 4 months of June, July, August, and September; corresponding numerically to months 6,7,8, and 9 in my data. I'm also differentiating by "treatment" and want each year plotted separately, so I am using the facet function.

Here is some sample data:

```
 treatment      date  year month   Day  mean_VWC
      <chr>     <chr> <int> <int> <int>     <dbl>
1   control  1/1/2016  2016     1     1 0.2607630
2   control  1/1/2017  2017     1     1 0.2688776
3   control 1/10/2016  2016     1    10 0.2780299
4   control 1/10/2017  2017     1    10 0.2477122
5   control 1/11/2016  2016     1    11 0.2847904
6   control 1/11/2017  2017     1    11 0.2627695
```

Here is the code I'm using:

```
ggplot(soil.mc_day, aes(as.factor(month), mean_VWC, fill=treatment)) +
  geom_boxplot(position=position_dodge(width=1), size = .5, outlier.colour = "black", color="black") +
  facet_wrap(~ year) +
  scale_x_discrete(limit = c(6,7,8,9),
                   labels=as.character(c("Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep")))
```

[Here is the resulting plots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wv41X.jpg)

As you can see, it is truncating the data how I want, but the x-axis ticks and labels are way off, even extending off the right end of the graph. Anyone have an idea what might be going on?

I'll also quickly mention, I've played around with the breaks function, without setting limits on the x-axis. It shows my x-axis aligned properly with the tricks/labels, but as you can see is plotting all of the data b/c I have not got the limit functions applied. Here is the code for that:

```
ggplot(soil.mc_day, aes(as.factor(month), mean_VWC, fill=treatment)) +
  geom_boxplot(position=position_dodge(width=1), size = .5, outlier.colour = "black", color="black") +
  facet_wrap(~ year) +
  scale_x_discrete(breaks = c(6,7,8,9),
                   labels=as.character(c("Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep"))) +
theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.3))
```

[And the resulting figure...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nDvVs.jpg)

So, my ultimate question is: what's going on the the x-axis labels in the first figure and how can I fix it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is hard to say without seeing the full data set but it seems that you are trying to constrain the data to be plotted within the ggplot call rather than before feeding the data into ggplot.

Have you tried filtering the data before running your plotting function?

Something like this:

```
df <- soil.mc_day %>%
  filter(month %in% seq(6, 9)) %>%
  mutate(month = factor(month, labels = c("June", "July", "August", "September"))
```

And then use your plot without the axis scaling.

```
df %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = month, y = mean_VMC, fill = treatment)) +
  geom_boxplot(position = position_dodge(width = 1), 
               size = 0.5, 
               color = "black", 
               outlier.color = "black") +
  facet_wrap(~ year)
```

Comment: Glad to hear! If this worked for you, please consider accepting the answer.